# Is there a better way to accomplish this PIXI rope mouse follower?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I've created a simple mouse follower using PIXI.js. It creates evenly spaced points based on mouse movement and renders a textured PIXI.Rope object along those points. PIXI seems to be having a difficult time rendering the rope and I'm wondering if there would be a better way to accomplish this or whether I'm misusing the Rope object.

As you can see in the example below, this works effectively for the most part, but moving the mouse quickly or moving the rope over the top of itself results in glitches and artifacts that likely have something to do with the way that PIXI renders gradients (and my misunderstanding of it).

Please see:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6dB6QcKvSFlcT4k3OrMH?p=preview

```
(function()
{
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
  {
    PIXI.Point = window.Vector;

    var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0xFFFFFF);
    var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(500, 500);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

    var resizeWindow = function()
    {
      w = window.innerWidth;
      h = window.innerHeight;
      renderer.resize(w,h);
      renderer.view.height = h;
      renderer.view.width = w;
    }
    resizeWindow()
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeWindow)

    var tRope, rope, skeleton;
    var isDrawing = true, points = [], pointsSkeleton = [], threshold_lower = 10, threshold_upper = 15, lineLength = 1000;
    var animate;

    tRope = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("http://new.wethecollective.com/junk/rope2.png");
    tRope.height = 22;
    tRope.width = 1000;
    tBone = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("http://new.wethecollective.com/junk/bone.png");
    tBone.height = 10;
    tBone.width = 10;

    var addPoint = function(point, addToSkeleton)
    {
      if(addToSkeleton !== false)
      {
        addToSkeleton = true
      }

      points.push(point);

      if(addToSkeleton)
      {
        var bone = new PIXI.Sprite(tBone);
        bone.x = point.x - 5;
        bone.y = point.y - 5;
        pointsSkeleton[points.length -1] = skeleton.addChild(bone);
      }
    }
    var removePoint = function(index)
    {
      points.splice(index, 1);

      skeleton.removeChild(pointsSkeleton[index]);
      pointsSkeleton.splice(index, 1);
    }

    animate = function()
    {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      // render the stage   
      renderer.render(stage);
    }

    var rlength = 0
    while(rlength < lineLength)
    {
      rlength += threshold_upper;
      addPoint(new PIXI.Point(rlength, 100), false);
    }

    rope = new PIXI.Rope(tRope, points);
    skeleton = new PIXI.DisplayObjectContainer();

    stage.addChild(rope);
    stage.addChild(skeleton);

    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e)
    {
      var pos = new PIXI.Point(e.clientX, e.clientY);
      var v = pos.clone().sub(points[points.length - 1]);
      l = v.length()
      if(l > threshold_lower)
      {
        if(l <= threshold_upper)
        {
          addPoint(pos);
        } else
        {
          var segment_l = 0;
          var divisions = Math.floor(l / threshold_upper)
          var divisionlength = l / divisions;
          var lastPos = points[points.length - 1];
          for(var i = 0; i < divisions; i++)
          {
            var v1 = v.clone();
            v1.setLength(divisionlength);
            v1.add(lastPos);
            addPoint(v1);
            segment_l += v1.length();
            lastPos = v1;
          }
        }
      }

      totalLength = 0;
      for(var i =0; i < points.length; i++)
      {
        if(i>0)
        {
          totalLength += points[i-1].clone().sub(points[i]).length()
        }
      }

      if(totalLength > lineLength)
      {
        var pointsnum = points.length;
        for(var i=0; i < pointsnum; i++)
        {
          var p = points[i].clone();
          totalLength -= p.sub(points[i+1]).length()
          removePoint(i);
          i--;
          pointsnum--;
          if(totalLength <= lineLength)
          {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    });

    animate();
  });
})();

(function(NS)
{
  /*
  * @class Vector
  * @constructor 
  * @param x {Number} position of the point
  * @param y {Number} position of the point
  */
  NS.Vector = function(x, y)
  {
      /**
       * @property x 
       * @type Number
       * @default 0
       */
      this.x = x || 0;

      /**
       * @property y
       * @type Number
       * @default 0
       */
      this.y = y || 0;
  };

  /**
   * Creates a clone of this point
   *
   * @method clone
   * @return {Vector} a copy of the point
   */
  NS.Vector.prototype.clone = function()
  {
      return new NS.Vector(this.x, this.y);
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.add = function(v) {
      this.x += v.x;
      this.y += v.y;
      return this;
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.sub = function(v) {
      this.x -= v.x;
      this.y -= v.y;
      return this;
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.invert = function(v) {
      this.x *= -1;
      this.y *= -1;
      return this;
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.multiplyScalar = function(s) {
      this.x *= s;
      this.y *= s;
      return this;
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.divideScalar = function(s) {
      if(s === 0) {
          this.x = 0;
          this.y = 0;
      } else {
          var invScalar = 1 / s;
          this.x *= invScalar;
          this.y *= invScalar;
      }
      return this;
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.dot = function(v) {
      return this.x * v.x + this.y * v.y;
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.length = function(v) {
      return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.lengthSq = function() {
      return this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y;
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.normalize = function() {
      return this.divideScalar(this.length());
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.distanceTo = function(v) {
      return Math.sqrt(this.distanceToSq(v));
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.distanceToSq = function(v) {
      var dx = this.x - v.x, dy = this.y - v.y;
      return dx * dx + dy * dy;
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.set = function(x, y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      return this;
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.setX = function(x) {
      this.x = x;
      return this;
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.setY = function(y) {
      this.y = y;
      return this;
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.setLength = function(l) {
      var oldLength = this.length();
      if(oldLength !== 0 && l !== oldLength) {
          this.multiplyScalar(l / oldLength);
      }
      return this;
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.invert = function(v) {
      this.x *= -1;
      this.y *= -1;
      return this;
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.lerp = function(v, alpha) {
      this.x += (v.x - this.x) * alpha;
      this.y += (v.y - this.y) * alpha;
      return this;
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.rad = function() {
      return Math.atan2(this.x, this.y);
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.deg = function() {
      return this.rad() * 180 / Math.PI;
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.equals = function(v) {
      return this.x === v.x && this.y === v.y;
  };

  NS.Vector.prototype.rotate = function(theta) {
      var xtemp = this.x;
      this.x = this.x * Math.cos(theta) - this.y * Math.sin(theta);
      this.y = xtemp * Math.sin(theta) + this.y * Math.cos(theta);
      return this;
  };

  // constructor
  NS.Vector.prototype.constructor = NS.Vector;


})(window)
```

Please forgive my spaghetti code. I've just been building this out as a proof of concept at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by physically removing the rope from stage and reinitialising it on each render pass. It feels a little hacky to me, but it does work.

```
animate = function()
{
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  stage.removeChild(rope);
  rope = new PIXI.Rope(tRope, points);
  stage.addChildAt(rope,0);

  // render the stage   
  renderer.render(stage);
}
```